# Ionic 4: Hardware Back Button Reloading Application

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Working on a Project and stuck in an Issue:

Hardware Back Button Reloading Application (I am using Angular Router in this application).

My Code to Exit Application:

```
  ionViewDidEnter(){
      this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{
          navigator['app'].exitApp();
      });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave(){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

While same logic Working in other applications. but in this application its reloading the application not exiting it.

P.S: i have also tried it to put in `platform.ready()` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

As Mention by [@rtpHarry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156388/rtpharry) template of SideMenu / Tabs have History which leads application to Reload it self on root page. i was able to solve this by clearing History.

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  navigator['app'].clearHistory();    
}
```

on Your Root Page just Clear your history and your Hardware Back Button will close the Application instead of Reloading it.

Answer (score 3):

With **IONIC 4**, there is new method `subscribeWithPriority` developed to handle race between soft & hard back button. Try modifying your code like below:

```
 this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(1, () => {
        navigator['app'].exitApp();
 });
```

> `subscribeWithPriority()` stops the propagation of the event after its execution and if we subscribe with high priority and execute our prefered navigation instead of default one then it is going to work as you want.

**More reference docs for details:** 

 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/commit/6a5aec8b5d76280ced5e8bb8fd9ea6fe75fe6795

 https://medium.com/@aleksandarmitrev/ionic-hardware-back-button-nightmare-9f4af35cbfb0

**UPDATES:**

- Try using this new version of exitApp [cordova plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-exit). I haven't
  tried myself but looks promising from popularity.
- Also try to empty the page stack from Navcontroller or go to your home screen, seems like that's causing the reload for app with sidemenu's & tab pages...    `this.navCtrl.pop() / this._navCtrl.navigateBack('HomeScreen')`, and then call `exitApp`.

**NOTE:** Tabs & SideMenu as those have its own routing module does create lot of complexity with app navigation.

Comment: Not Working. Sorry i didn't mention in my question that i already tried `subscribeWithPriority()`.

Comment: Doesn't look like you did say you had tried `subscribeWithPriority` :)

Comment: @NajamusSaqib - sorry had been busy with my projects, updated my answer with certain things you can try.

Comment: `this.platform.exitApp()` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a sidemenu in your app? I'm just curious because this seems to be when I get this problem as well.

If you look in your inspector, you will see that `window.history` has a length of 1.

I don't see it in some of my apps, but the app that I have a side menu setup acts this way - on the homepage if you press back the screen goes white then it reloads the app.

Like I say, looking in the inspector shows that there is a history to step back to, which it is trying to do, and whatever that history step is, it just pushes it forward back to the homepage, which made me wonder if it was the sidemenu setting up its own control of the navigation system.

I've probably said some poorly worded terminology but as I haven't solved this myself I thought I would just let you know what I had found... hopefully it helps you move forward.

In my scenario, I wasn't even trying to do the exit on back code - I just noticed that the app would appear to "reboot" if I kept pressing back.

Comment: Its TABS based application. I will look for this history length. Thanks

Comment: Yes i checked it.  history have length of 1. I have Tabs in my app. May be tabs are controlling the routing.

Comment: if this helped but didnt totally solve it, please consider upvoting, it counts towards my ionic4 badge and makes me happy :) I hope you figure it out because its been bugging me. I suspect its actually a bug in Ionic itself. If I recall correctly it doesn't do it all the time - maybe running on the browser its fine, but installed as an app it does it - can't be sure if thats what it was.

Comment: it helped me partially, but i am unable to solve this right now. looking deep into it. 1 more thing. In Emulator(Android v9) back button closing the application. but in real device (Android v7) application reloading itself. so it might have something related to android Versions.

Comment: yeah upvote means "this answer is useful" (hover over the upvote button to see this appear), mark as answer means "this answer completely solved the problem". My experience was that when I ran it on my huawei p20 pro it was doing this, but not when i was developing / testing it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This explain the solution on Ionic 5 (and 4.6+ too I think).

```
private backButtonSub: Subscription;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.backButtonSub = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(
    10000,
    () => {
        // do your stuff
    }
  );
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
  this.backButtonSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

also keep

```
IonicModule.forRoot({
  hardwareBackButton: true
}),
```

to `true` (default) in your `app.module.ts`

Sources:

- https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20191122-CustomizingAndroidBackButtonInIonic4.html
- The Doc

Comment: i Think `IonicModule.forRoot({
  hardwareBackButton: true
}),` will close application on all/any Page. what if user only wants to close application from root page not from other pages?

Comment: Thanks for your question for clarification, I'll do my best to answer. The propriety as  "hardwareBackButton: true" covers all the cases in the way that you can always set your custom beheviour for the current view, and so to forward the view close request in same cases or handle it differently in others you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i'l test it in some of my scenarios and let you know the result.